# WooCommerce REST API include attributes or custom fields in search

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

I need an extended search functionality available via REST API - mainly an ability to include product's attributes in a search query.

I've seen a lot of similar questions but none of them are answered unfortunately. Is this even possible? And if so, any advice how or where I could modify the search query to include the product's attributes?

Answer (score 0):

/wp-json/wc/v3/products   -  List all products

`attribute` - Limit result set to products with a specific attribute:

sample: https://your-site.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products?consumer_key=ck_yourconsumerkey&consumer_secret=cs_yourconsumersecret&attribute=attr-name

`attribute_term` - Limit result set to products with a specific attribute term ID (required an assigned attribute).

sample: https://your-site.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products?consumer_key=ck_yourconsumerkey&consumer_secret=cs_yourconsumersecret&attribute_term=2457

more info here: https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#list-all-products