# WooCommerce REST API using custom attributes in search

Tags: javascript, rest, woocommerce, custom-attributes, woocommerce-rest-api

I've seen this question asked a couple times but nobody has any answers..

I can't seem to get the REST call for /products working either? I can successfully make a call (over http) with params: seach, orderby, perpage and all the oauth_* params. I am trying to now query the same url with custom attribute for barcode. Documentation says add a param called attribute(barcode) in my case and then add attribute_term for the variable, but every call returns same data as the original blank parameter products call..

Is anybody having any luck with custom attributes here? V1 api (not legacy).. Over http..

Reference to another similar problem with no answer - [WooCommerce REST API include attributes or custom fields in search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38201510/woocommerce-rest-api-include-attributes-or-custom-fields-in-search)

Comment: The new v2 api solves a lot of the API issues including attributes and variations.